# How come I'm having trouble cp this file to another directory?

Tags: bash, git, terminal, zsh, git-bash

cp fanpage.html path/Desktop

I am using this command to cp the fanpage.html file from my prework-about-me directory to my Desktop directory. When I run the exact command I posted here how come it keeps telling me "cp: path/Desktop: No such file or directory".

How should my command look? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you really using `path/Desktop` or is `path` just a placeholder for a real path? The message is clear - you have to create `path/Desktop` before cp'ing something to it: `mkdir -p path/Desktop`

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck

Comment: @AustinCoen: What does `ls -ld path/Desktop` say? Did you really create this directory?

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood an example. You shouldn't literally type "path" but instead the actual path to the file. Here, the terminal is looking for a directory named "path" in your current directory. If, for example, Desktop is a folder in your current directory, you should simply type in

```
cp fanpage.html Desktop
```

or for example if it were to be in another folder named "foo":

```
cp fanpage.html foo/Desktop
```

If you ever have doubts about these kinds of things, you can use the "man" (short for manual) command. Simply type in man then the command you want to know about.

Comment: good to know, thank you!